# How to access instance variables to test `receive` in a spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following spec fragment:

```
  it 'should create company and user' do
    company_iv = assigns(:company)
    user_iv = assigns(:user)
    expect(subject).to receive(:create_timeline_event).with(company_iv, user_iv)
    expect { post :create, params }.to change { User.count }.by(1).and change { Company.count }.by(1)
```

and traditionally use the receive syntax to test calling a method. I normally call it before the call to post in the above fragment. How would I access the instance variable of the user and the company for this spec?

Comment: why do you need the instance variable, you can just get the `User` and `Company` object by doing `.last` on both, if that's what you are after

Comment: thx @Subash -  i don't use this syntax that much but they won't be created at that point. Like how would I access them since receive needs to be called before the call to post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to jam a few different tests into a single `it` statement. Here's how I would approach this:

```
it 'creates company and user' do
  expect { post :create, params }
    .to change { User.count }.by(1)
    .and change { Company.count }.by(1)
end

it 'assigns instance variables' do
  post :create, params

  expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(Company.last)
  expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(User.last)
end

it 'calls create_timeline_event with newly created company and user' do
  allow(some_object).to receive(:create_timeline_event)

  post :create, params

  expect(some_object)
    .to have_received(:create_timeline_event)
    .with(Company.last, User.last)
end
```

Note that these tests are going to be slow because they hit the database. Another approach to this is to use mocks. That would look something like this:

```
let(:params) { ... }
let(:company) { instance_double(Company) }
let(:user) { instance_double(User) }

before do 
  allow(Company).to receive(:create).and_return(company)
  allow(User).to receive(:create).and_return(user)
  allow(some_object).to receive(:create_timeline_event)

  post :create, params
end

it 'creates company and user' do
  expect(Company).to have_received(:create).with(company_params)
  expect(User).to have_received(:create).with(user_params)
end

it 'assigns instance variables' do 
  expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
  expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
end

it 'calls create_timeline_event with newly created company and user' do
  expect(some_object)
    .to have_received(:create_timeline_event)
    .with(company, user)
end
```

These tests do not hit the database at all, meaning that they'll execute much faster.

Comment: thx - have_received is using a spy? - we tend not to use them at work (but could). And yes we do hit the database because there's a lot of stored procedures so would gladly take a few more minutes for the higher level of certainty that things are working as anticipated.

Comment: `allow` creates the spy. `expect(...).to have_received` checks it. You do the `allow` before the call, and `have_received` after it.